# The type of oops in Isabelle

Tags: types, isabelle, isar

[Section 6.1.3 of the Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf#page=142)

states that the type of oops is

> proof → local_theory | theory

What is this type `proof`? Is this the umbrella type for proof(prove), proof(state) and proof(chain)?

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the case: `oops` can be used at any point at all inside a proof block to abort the current proof attempt and return to the top theory level.